# Is the term "open execution" wrong in any way?

Tags: consensus

I read a [post](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-open-execution-replace-source-jason-carver) discussing Ethereum, and how it can be thought of as the next step of the "open source" movement of software, and he coined the term "open execution," and I rather liked it.

The real question is whether or not this misses the mark, or only grasps a portion of the whole picture.  If it does, is there a similar way of putting it that hits the nail on the head?

Comment: I agree, we should avoid that term. However, this question is of a [subjective nature](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) and might lead to discussions. Please consult the help center for more information on [how to ask](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on stack exchange.